# After using media query boxes are being displayed incorrectly

Tags: html, css

[Even though the width is greater than 992px boxes are no in one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciN9B.png)
[Below 992 it is overlapping , it should not as I have set the margin 20px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iulcI.png)
[overlappin of text as I squeeze the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61hl1.png)

I want to create a menu page with three boxes: chicken, beef, and sushi. When the screen dimensions are greater than or equal to >=992px, all three boxes should occupy an equal width of 33.33%. When the dimensions are between 767=<px and =<991px, two of the boxes should have equal width (50%) and the third should occupy the full width. When the screen dimensions are below =<766px, all three boxes should also occupy the full width. Currently, when I squeeze the window, the boxes overlap and the text overflows outside its respective div. Is there a way to solve this text problem other than using word wrap?

HTML code:

```
<body>
   <h1>Our Menu</h1>
   <section>
      <div class="column-lg-4 colmn-md-6 colmn-sm-12">
         <p class="p1"><b>Chicken</b></p>
         <p class="food">The country that consumes the greatest amount of chicken is the United States. Every year, the United States consumes approximately 15,000 metric tons of chicken, placing it significantly in front of the second-place region. The United States adds chicken to just about everything.</p>
       </div> 
   </section>
   <section>
       <div class="column-lg-4 colmn-md-6 colmn-sm-12">
           <p class="p2"><b>Beef</b></p>
           <p class="food">Beef is the culinary name for meat from cattle. In prehistoric times, humankind hunted aurochs and later domesticated them. Since that time, numerous breeds of cattle have been bred specifically for the quality or quantity of their meat.</p>
       </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="column-lg-4 colmn-md-12 colmn-sm-12">
            <p class="p3"><b>Sushi</b></p>
            <p class="food">Sushi is a Japanese dish of prepared vinegared rice, usually with some sugar and salt, accompanied by a variety of ingredients, such as seafood—often raw—and vegetables. Styles of sushi and its presentation vary widely, but the one key ingredient is "sushi rice", also referred to as shari, or sumeshi.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}

div {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(104, 98, 98);
}

section {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 20px;
}

.p1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(240, 145, 145);
    font-family: cursive;
}

.p2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin: 0%;
    color: white;
    background-color: brown;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.p3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    margin: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(247, 247, 153);
    font-family: cursive;
}

.food {
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: cursive;
}

/* Large Devices (Desktop Version) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .column-lg-4 {
        float: left;
        width: 33.33%;
    }
}

/* Medium Devices (Tablet version) */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .colmn-md-6 {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .colmn-md-12 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}

/* Small Devices (mobile version) */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .colmn-sm-12 {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: For once, you should not use `float` in 2023 for aligning elements next to each other. It has been a misused hack from before 2012. `float` is a property to float an element within flow-text such as an image within a newspaper article. Use Flexbox or CSS-Grid which are the correct tools and properly even solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

as saying @tacoshi, in 2023, lot better to use grid to structure your page

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

#menuContainer {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Small Devices (mobile version) */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #menuContainer {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}


/* Medium Devices (Tablet version) */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  #menuContainer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
  #menuContainer section:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: auto / span 2;
  }
}


/* Large Devices (Desktop Version) */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #menuContainer {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(104, 98, 98);
}

section>div {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.p1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(240, 145, 145);
  font-family: cursive;
}

.p2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin: 0%;
  color: white;
  background-color: brown;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.p3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin: 0%;
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 153);
  font-family: cursive;
}

.food {
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: cursive;
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
<div id="menuContainer">
  <section>
    <div class="">
      <p class="p1"><b>Chicken</b></p>
      <p class="food">The country that consumes the greatest amount of chicken is the United States. Every year, the United States consumes approximately 15,000 metric tons of chicken, placing it significantly in front of the second-place region. The United States adds
        chicken to just about everything.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="">
      <p class="p2"><b>Beef</b></p>
      <p class="food">Beef is the culinary name for meat from cattle. In prehistoric times, humankind hunted aurochs and later domesticated them. Since that time, numerous breeds of cattle have been bred specifically for the quality or quantity of their meat.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="">
      <p class="p3"><b>Sushi</b></p>
      <p class="food">Sushi is a Japanese dish of prepared vinegared rice, usually with some sugar and salt, accompanied by a variety of ingredients, such as seafood—often raw—and vegetables. Styles of sushi and its presentation vary widely, but the one key ingredient
        is "sushi rice", also referred to as shari, or sumeshi.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```